# Notifications dismissed from lockscreen after unlock

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, android-12, realme

### Explanation of the problem

0. Ensure show notifications on lock screen is enabled in the settings
1. Receive a notification and it displays on the lockscreen
2. Unlock the screen
3. Lock the screen
4. The notification is no longer displayed on the lockscreen (or notification drawer)
5. Unlock the screen
6. Notification shows as an icon in the notification shade and if you open the notification drawer.

The device: realme 7 pro
Android version: Android 12 (realme UI 3.0)

Here is a video of the problem https://imgur.com/a/MM7mOGn

#### Research

I have seen the following threads which have the same problem and show it is likely to be a bad UI/UX decision for realme UI (and MIUI)  android version 12 and up:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/11cuep7/notifications_disappear_from_lockscreen_after/
- https://c.realme.com/in/post-details/1375788112633995264
- https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/any-way-to-keep-notifications-on-lockscreen.3941709/

---

### Question

Are their any workarounds for this annoying behaviour?

Comment: Note: this is not the default behaviour on stock android 12 and up.

Comment: Or any version of stock android.

Comment: My phone has just started doing this and it's driving me mad

Comment: no workarounds found yet @Greg